# How to enable and disable button based on checkbox selection in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, checkbox

I have a button and textfield and a checkbox. initially checkbox is checked. when i uncheck the checkbox both button and textbox should be disabled. how to achieve this.

Comment: what code you have tried so far? It would be great to understand the code and suggest you batter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well make a listener on checkbox. When the checkbox is unchecked, disable the buttonField and the textbox. See an example below:

```
yourCheckBox.setChangeListener(this);
add(yourCheckBox);
add(textfield);
add(buttonfield);

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
   if (field == yourCheckBox) {
      if (!youCheckBox.getChecked()) {
         textfield.setEditable(false);
         buttonfield.setEditable(false);
      }
   }
}
```